# Optimized solution to convert numbers to percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, loops, optimization

I have a JSON object, for an instance which gives me the value from 1-10.
For value 1 I need to map the percentage to 100, 
    value 2 to 90, value 3 to 80 ...

As a beginner, I can use a switch statement with 10 cases or an if else statement. But I would like to know best-optimized way of doing it with loops.

```
function levelUpdate(data) {
    var percentage;
    if (data >= 3 || data <= 13) {
        switch (data) {
            case 3:
                percentage = 100;
                break;
            case 4:
                percentage = 90;
                break;
            case 5:
                percentage = 80;
                break;
            case 6:
                percentage = 70;
                break;
            case 7:
                percentage = 60;
                break;
            case 8:
                percentage = 50;
                break;
            case 9:
                percentage = 40;
                break;
            case 10:
                percentage = 30;
                break;
            case 11:
                percentage = 20;
                break;
            case 12:
                percentage = 10;
                break;
            case 13:
                percentage = 0;
                break;
            default:
                percentage = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your questions is unclear at the moment. Please add some relevant code to create a [mcve].

Comment: To be honest, a `switch` would be pretty fast. If you start doing arithmetic, then it's probably going to be *less* optimised as you execute more operations to derive the answer. And a loop would mean even more operations still.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a function for getting the value.

```js
const f = x => 110 - x * 10;

var x;

for (x = 1; x <= 10; x++) console.log(x, f(x));
```